# Debug Pascal's Triangle

Tags: javascript, arrays, pascals-triangle

Could someone please walk me through as to what I did incorrectly on Pascal's Triangle in Javascript? I saw a thread that already exists using recursion however, without copying verbatim, the code, in my eyes, looks too similar to decipher what I'm doing wrong. I could use some fresh eyes on what I've missed or could improve. Thank you

```js
var pTri = [[1]]

function pascalTriangle(num, pTri) {

  if (num < 2) {
    return pTri;
  }

  var newRow = [1];
  var lastRow = pTri[pTri.length - 1];

  console.log(lastRow)

  for (var i = 1; i < lastRow.length; i++) {
    var addToNewRow = lastRow[i] + lastRow[i - 1];
    newRow.push(addToNewRow);
    }

  pTri.push(newRow);

 return pascalTriangle(num - 1, pTri);
}

pascalTriangle(2, pTri)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looks like you added a new array 'addToNewRow' by mistake.

```js
var pTri = [[1]]

function pascalTriangle(num, pTri) {

  if (num < 2) {
    return pTri;
  }

  var newRow = [1];
  var lastRow = pTri[pTri.length - 1];

  console.log(lastRow)

  for (var i = 1; i < lastRow.length; i++) {
    newRow[i] = lastRow[i] + lastRow[i - 1];
  }
    
  newRow.push(1);

  pTri.push(newRow);

 return pascalTriangle(num - 1, pTri);
}

pascalTriangle(10, pTri)
```

Comment: This certainly looks like what the question was after, but to be clear this answer assumes that `num` is the number of rows in the output triangle. This solution does not, for instance, generate a pascals triangle given a desired counting number.

Comment: @JakeHolzinger good catch, I didn't review quite that closely.

Comment: ok this f'd me up just a tad... could you elaborate on the difference between the two? I'm a bit of a junior here. I thought num, being the rows of the output triangle, was the equivalent to the desired counting (of rows)  number

Comment: Also is:

     newRow[i] = lastRow[i] + lastRow[i - 1]

the equivalent to:

newRow += addToNewRow

Comment: The counting number is the second number in each row (obviously excluding the first row), it goes up incrementally with each row, hence the name "counting number". To elaborate if `num` was supposed to be the counting number, then you would expect to have 11 rows of output not 10.

Comment: @KnowMeNot no those are not equal, or even similar. the former is assigning a value to an array index, and the latter is adding a value to a number after subtracting 1 from the value